# Limiting URL accessibility in Flutter WebView plugin

Tags: flutter, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

I started using Flutter's WebView plugin to show a Facebook feed in my application. I am wanting to limit what the application user is allowed to do in the application webview, in other words, I don't want them to be able to access another other facebook domains that are outside of the initial page that I am showing. I don't want the user to be able to log in to Facebook but rather than just be able to see this open Facebook Feed that doesn't require an account.

I tried hosting the Facebook Page plugin which is an iFrame or Javascript SDK plugin, but I haven't had any luck since the webview isn't made to handle this. Instead, I decided to just link to the Facebook Page via the URL. I want to avoid the user from browsing all over Facebook, so the best way that I can think is to limit the URLs.

I am using the WebView widget:

```
return WebView(
   initialUrl: 'https://www.facebook.com/specific-facebook-page-here',
   javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.disabled,
);
```

Is there any way where I can monitor their URL and avoid them accessing portions of the Facebook Domain?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In navigationDelegate compare url string, the demo is block https://flutter.dev/docs and https://www.youtube.com/

```
navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
              print('blocking navigation to $request}');
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://flutter.dev/docs')) {
              print('blocking navigation to $request}');
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            print('allowing navigation to $request');
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
```

full code

```
// Copyright 2018 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: WebViewExample()));

const String kNavigationExamplePage = '''
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head><title>Navigation Delegate Example</title></head>
<body>
<p>
The navigation delegate is set to block navigation to the youtube website.
</p>
<ul>
<ul><a href="https://www.youtube.com/">https://www.youtube.com/</a></ul>
<ul><a href="https://www.google.com/">https://www.google.com/</a></ul>
<ul><a href="https://www.google.com/">https://nodejs.org/en</a></ul>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
''';

class WebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WebViewExampleState createState() => _WebViewExampleState();
}

class _WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
  Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter WebView example'),
        // This drop down menu demonstrates that Flutter widgets can be shown over the web view.
        actions: <Widget>[
          NavigationControls(_controller.future),
          SampleMenu(_controller.future),
        ],
      ),
      // We're using a Builder here so we have a context that is below the Scaffold
      // to allow calling Scaffold.of(context) so we can show a snackbar.
      body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _controller.complete(webViewController);
          },
          // TODO(iskakaushik): Remove this when collection literals makes it to stable.
          // ignore: prefer_collection_literals
          javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
            _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
          ].toSet(),
          navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
              print('blocking navigation to $request}');
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://flutter.dev/docs')) {
              print('blocking navigation to $request}');
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            print('allowing navigation to $request');
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            print('Page finished loading: $url');
          },
        );
      }),
      floatingActionButton: favoriteButton(),
    );
  }

  JavascriptChannel _toasterJavascriptChannel(BuildContext context) {
    return JavascriptChannel(
        name: 'Toaster',
        onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text(message.message)),
          );
        });
  }

  Widget favoriteButton() {
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
        future: _controller.future,
        builder: (BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
          if (controller.hasData) {
            return FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final String url = await controller.data.currentUrl();
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  SnackBar(content: Text('Favorited $url')),
                );
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.favorite),
            );
          }
          return Container();
        });
  }
}

enum MenuOptions {
  showUserAgent,
  listCookies,
  clearCookies,
  addToCache,
  listCache,
  clearCache,
  navigationDelegate,
}

class SampleMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  SampleMenu(this.controller);

  final Future<WebViewController> controller;
  final CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
      future: controller,
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
        return PopupMenuButton<MenuOptions>(
          onSelected: (MenuOptions value) {
            switch (value) {
              case MenuOptions.showUserAgent:
                _onShowUserAgent(controller.data, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.listCookies:
                _onListCookies(controller.data, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.clearCookies:
                _onClearCookies(context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.addToCache:
                _onAddToCache(controller.data, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.listCache:
                _onListCache(controller.data, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.clearCache:
                _onClearCache(controller.data, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.navigationDelegate:
                _onNavigationDelegateExample(controller.data, context);
                break;
            }
          },
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>>[
            PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.showUserAgent,
              child: const Text('Show user agent'),
              enabled: controller.hasData,
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.listCookies,
              child: Text('List cookies'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.clearCookies,
              child: Text('Clear cookies'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.addToCache,
              child: Text('Add to cache'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.listCache,
              child: Text('List cache'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.clearCache,
              child: Text('Clear cache'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.navigationDelegate,
              child: Text('Navigation Delegate example'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _onShowUserAgent(
      WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    // Send a message with the user agent string to the Toaster JavaScript channel we registered
    // with the WebView.
    controller.evaluateJavascript(
        'Toaster.postMessage("User Agent: " + navigator.userAgent);');
  }

  void _onListCookies(
      WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    final String cookies =
    await controller.evaluateJavascript('document.cookie');
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text('Cookies:'),
          _getCookieList(cookies),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }

  void _onAddToCache(WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    await controller.evaluateJavascript(
        'caches.open("test_caches_entry"); localStorage["test_localStorage"] = "dummy_entry";');
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
      content: Text('Added a test entry to cache.'),
    ));
  }

  void _onListCache(WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    await controller.evaluateJavascript('caches.keys()'
        '.then((cacheKeys) => JSON.stringify({"cacheKeys" : cacheKeys, "localStorage" : localStorage}))'
        '.then((caches) => Toaster.postMessage(caches))');
  }

  void _onClearCache(WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    await controller.clearCache();
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
      content: Text("Cache cleared."),
    ));
  }

  void _onClearCookies(BuildContext context) async {
    final bool hadCookies = await cookieManager.clearCookies();
    String message = 'There were cookies. Now, they are gone!';
    if (!hadCookies) {
      message = 'There are no cookies.';
    }
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(message),
    ));
  }

  void _onNavigationDelegateExample(
      WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    final String contentBase64 =
    base64Encode(const Utf8Encoder().convert(kNavigationExamplePage));
    controller.loadUrl('data:text/html;base64,$contentBase64');
  }

  Widget _getCookieList(String cookies) {
    if (cookies == null || cookies == '""') {
      return Container();
    }
    final List<String> cookieList = cookies.split(';');
    final Iterable<Text> cookieWidgets =
    cookieList.map((String cookie) => Text(cookie));
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: cookieWidgets.toList(),
    );
  }
}

class NavigationControls extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigationControls(this._webViewControllerFuture)
      : assert(_webViewControllerFuture != null);

  final Future<WebViewController> _webViewControllerFuture;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
      future: _webViewControllerFuture,
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> snapshot) {
        final bool webViewReady =
            snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done;
        final WebViewController controller = snapshot.data;
        return Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              onPressed: !webViewReady
                  ? null
                  : () async {
                if (await controller.canGoBack()) {
                  controller.goBack();
                } else {
                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(content: Text("No back history item")),
                  );
                  return;
                }
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
              onPressed: !webViewReady
                  ? null
                  : () async {
                if (await controller.canGoForward()) {
                  controller.goForward();
                } else {
                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(
                        content: Text("No forward history item")),
                  );
                  return;
                }
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.replay),
              onPressed: !webViewReady
                  ? null
                  : () {
                controller.reload();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

You can see block information in demo picture

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I am looking for!